# How to automatically show difference of values between rows (Vue.js Data tables)

Tags: vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

How to automatically calculate difference of values between current and previous row. I use "Data tables" in Vue with Vuetify.
In my code i added static values to illustrate what i want to do ("Calories change" column). This column shouldn't be available for adding and editing.

**Example:**
[image: example image]

If previous value is more than current - I would like display "-" with difference value.

If previous value is less than current - I would like display "+" with difference value.

If values are the same - I would like display "0".

In this example the point is that I would like to know how many (more, less or the same) calories I ate in the following days.

Could someone help with this case?

**Demo:** [Codepen](https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/mdOrEqj)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="results"
      sort-by="date"
      sort-desc
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar
          flat
        >
          <v-toolbar-title>Data</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider
            class="mx-4"
            inset
            vertical
          ></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            max-width="500px"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                dark
                class="mb-2"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              >
                Add new
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>
  
              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="6"
                    >
                      <v-menu
                        ref="dateMenu"
                        v-model="dateMenu"
                        :close-on-content-click="false"
                        :return-value.sync="editedItem.date"
                        transition="scale-transition"
                        offset-y
                        min-width="auto"
                      >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                          <v-text-field
                            v-model="editedItem.date"
                            label="Select date"
                            prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                            readonly
                            v-bind="attrs"
                            v-on="on"
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </template>
                        <v-date-picker
                          v-model="editedItem.date"
                          no-title
                          scrollable
                        >
                          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                          <v-btn
                            text
                            color="primary"
                            @click="dateMenu = false"
                          >
                            Cancel
                          </v-btn>
                          <v-btn
                            text
                            color="primary"
                            @click="$refs.dateMenu.save(editedItem.date)"
                          >
                            OK
                          </v-btn>
                        </v-date-picker>
                      </v-menu>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="12"
                      sm="6"
                      md="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="editedItem.calories"
                        label="Calories"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>
  
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn
                  color="blue darken-1"
                  text
                  @click="close"
                >
                  Cancel
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  color="blue darken-1"
                  text
                  @click="save"
                >
                  Save
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title class="headline">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</v-card-title>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeDelete">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="deleteItemConfirm">OK</v-btn>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <v-icon
          small
          class="mr-2"
          @click="editItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-pencil
        </v-icon>
        <v-icon
          small
          @click="deleteItem(item)"
        >
          mdi-delete
        </v-icon>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        No results
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    dateMenu: false,
    dialog: false,
    dialogDelete: false,
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Date',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: true,
        value: 'date',
      },
      { text: 'Calories (kcal)', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Calories difference', value: 'caloriesChange', sortable: false },
      { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
    ],
    results: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      calories: 0,
      // this should calculate automatically
      caloriesChange: 0,
    },
    defaultItem: {
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      calories: 0,
      // this should calculate automatically
      caloriesChange: 0,
    },
  }),

  computed: {
    formTitle () {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
    },
  },

  watch: {
    dialog (val) {
      val || this.close()
    },
    dialogDelete (val) {
      val || this.closeDelete()
    },
  },

  created () {
    this.initialize()
  },

  methods: {
    initialize () {
      this.results = [
        {
          date: '2021-01-09',
          calories: 2905,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '+ ' + 55 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-08',
          calories: 2850,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '+ ' + 150 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-07',
          calories: 2700,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '- ' + 800 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-06',
          calories: 3500,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '+ ' + 300 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-05',
          calories: 3200,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '+ ' + 300 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-04',
          calories: 2900,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '' + 0 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-03',
          calories: 2900,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '- ' + 100 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-02',
          calories: 3000,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '- ' + 10 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2021-01-01',
          calories: 3010,
          // this should calculate automatically
          caloriesChange: '+ ' + 10 + ' kcal',
        },
        {
          date: '2020-12-31',
          calories: 3000,
          // this must be empty (first result)
          caloriesChange: '',
        },
      ]
    },

    editItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.results.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialog = true
    },

    deleteItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.results.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialogDelete = true
    },

    deleteItemConfirm () {
      this.results.splice(this.editedIndex, 1)
      this.closeDelete()
    },

    close () {
      this.dialog = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
        this.editedIndex = -1
      })
    },

    closeDelete () {
      this.dialogDelete = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
        this.editedIndex = -1
      })
    },

    save () {
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(this.results[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
      } else {
        this.results.push(this.editedItem)
      }
      this.close()
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about mapping a new array based on results using a computed getter?

Something like:

```
  computed: {
    ...,
    calcResults () {
      let sortedResults = this.results.sort(function(a, b){
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
       }).reverse();
      return sortedResults.map((result, index, results) => {
        let caloriesChange = index > 0 ? results[index].calories - results[index - 1].calories + ' kCal': '';
        return {
          date: result.date,
          calories: result.calories,
          caloriesChange: caloriesChange
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

And in your HTML:

```
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="calcResults"
      sort-by="date"
      sort-desc
      class="elevation-1"
    >
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :)  I tried your method, but the cell "caloriesChange" in the row for 2020-12-31 is not empty. The latest date (2021-01-09) is 0 kcal. When I try to edit a result, it creating again. Could I ask you for help in solving this problem? Here is your method: https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/BaQLpdv

Comment: Sure thing. Ah, I missed that. Updating my answer now.

Comment: When I try to add a new item (result), the value of "caloriesChange" is empty. I have no idea how to solve this. Here is screenshot:  https://i.ibb.co/8xLHtw2/example3.jpg

Comment: When I edit a value, it duplicates (a new item is created). Editing the item doesn't work properly. https://i.ibb.co/R4jk1Ct/example4.jpg

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Could you please help me with the last problem? Editing and deleting item doesn't work properly. I don't know why. https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/BaQLpdv

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in the `computed` field:

```js
computedResults() {
  return this.results.map((e, i, arr) => {
  let caloriesChange = i < arr.length - 1 ? arr[i + 1].calories - e.calories : '';
  if(caloriesChange > 0) {
    caloriesChange = `+${caloriesChange}`;
  }
  return {
    ...e,
    caloriesChange
   }
 });
}
```

And instead of passing `results`, pass `computedResults` in `<v-data-table />`:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="computedResults"
  sort-by="date"
  sort-desc
  class="elevation-1"
>
```

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/wheatup/pen/58823360a90f3cf43332f5e4a3486b3a?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I noticed that when I add a new result "caloriesChange" is empty and the last row "caloriesChange", instead of being empty, display a value. Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: When I try to edit a result, it adds new (duplicates).